# equality with inner product divided by norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, inner-products

For the question highlighted below, I've played around with the right side of the equality but am not sure how to express the left side in order to prove the equality.

Thanks in advance

> Let $f(x)=|x|$, $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$.  Show that if $x,y\neq 0$, then $$D_y f(x)=\dfrac{\langle x,y \rangle}{|x|}$$

Comment: Can you explain what the notation $D_yf(x)$ means?

Comment: Derivative in the $y$ direction

Comment: Do you know the definition?

Comment: Ah, that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}} = \frac{x_j}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}}}$, when $x \neq 0$. This means that $\nabla f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}x$, for $x \neq 0$. Finally for $y \neq 0$ we have that $D_y f(x) = \langle\nabla f(x),y\rangle = \frac{1}{|x|}\langle x, y \rangle$.